# By df.to_csv() I am writing data in a file, but I want to add some other data to the same file so I do not want the file to lose the previous data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

By the help of df.to_csv(...) I am writing a group of data from different places into a file, but whenever I add a new one the previous one is removed, so at the end instead of having all data I have only the last one written in the file.
How can I write data in a file without cleaning the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should probably have to add a "mode='a'" argument in the "to_csv()" command, to say you want to write to the file in append mode (otherwise the mode defaults to 'w', which indeed overwrites the previous content)

```
df.to_csv( *whatever arguments you already had*, mode = 'a')
```

Comment: You'll often want to set `header=False` for the appending writes too.

Comment: @DSM thanks for the addition, forgot about the headers

Comment: Thanks a lot indeed for your help and time, it worked properly